# R: apply on all matrix elements

Tags: r, apply

This seems so elementary that I am almost embarrassed to ask the question but I just can't get this to work. What would be the equivalent apply for this. This is a contrived example as I want to access the data for each cell with its row and column index but it represents the issue well.

```
ndat<-matrix(c(1:100), ncol=10)
for (i in 1:nrow(ndat)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(ndat)) {
        cat(ndat[i,j]," ")
    }  
    cat("\n")
}
```

Here is the actual problem. I am trying to plot the matrix on a grid. I know that textplot can plot matrices but I need more control on the grid. The location of the text depends on the row and column indices. The code is as follows:

```
plot.new()
tlx <- 0.04
tly <- 0.96
label_shift <- 0.04
text(tlx + label_shift, tly, "Columns", cex=1, adj=c(0,0))
text(tlx, tly - label_shift, "Rows", cex=1, adj=c(0,1), srt=-90)
ndat<-matrix(c(1:100), ncol=10)
dimnames(ndat) <- list(paste("R",1:10,sep=""), paste("C",1:10,sep=""))
row_name_space <- 0.1
col_name_space <- 0.1
data_width <- 0.075
data_height <- 0.075
x1 <- 1.5 * tlx 
x2 <- x1 + row_name_space + ncol(ndat) * data_width
y1 <- tly - 0.5*tlx
y2 <- y1 - col_name_space - nrow(ndat) * data_height
lines(c(x1,x1), c(y1,y2))
lines(c(x1,x2), c(y1,y1))
vertical_lseg <- function(n) {
        lx <- x1 + row_name_space + (n - 1) * data_width
        xv <- c(lx, lx)
        yv <- c(y1, y2)
        lines (xv, yv)
}
sapply(1:(ncol(ndat)+1), vertical_lseg)
horizontal_lseg <- function(n) {
        ly <- y1 - col_name_space - (n - 1) * data_height
        xv <- c(x1, x2)
        yv <- c(ly, ly)
        lines (xv, yv)
}
sapply(1:(nrow(ndat)+1), horizontal_lseg)
sapply(1:nrow(ndat), function(x) text(1.5 * tlx + row_name_space / 2, tly - 0.5*tlx - col_name_space - (x - 0.5) * data_height, rownames(ndat)[x], adj=c(0.5,0.5), cex=1))
sapply(1:ncol(ndat), function(x) text(1.5*tlx + col_name_space + (x - 0.5) * data_width, tly - 0.5*tlx - col_name_space /2, colnames(ndat)[x], adj=c(0.5,0.5), cex=1))
# This is where the text would be plotted. The calculation of x and y is right but the number of elements that outer produces seems to be 10,000
# rather than 100
outer(1:nrow(ndat), 1:ncol(ndat), FUN=function(r,c) text(1.5*tlx + col_name_space + (c - 0.5) * data_width, 
                                                         tly - 0.5*tlx - col_name_space - (r - 0.5) * data_height, 
                                                         toString(ndat[r,c]), adj=c(0.5,0.5), cex=1))
```

Comment: The correct answer will really depend on what you are trying to do. So, can you tell us the non-contrived problem that you are having?

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say without knowing what you want to do, but matrices are vectors with dimensions.  So vectorized functions will often work just fine directly:

```
ndat<-matrix(c(1:100), ncol=10)
ndat^2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1  121  441  961 1681 2601 3721 5041 6561  8281
 [2,]    4  144  484 1024 1764 2704 3844 5184 6724  8464
 [3,]    9  169  529 1089 1849 2809 3969 5329 6889  8649
 [4,]   16  196  576 1156 1936 2916 4096 5476 7056  8836
 [5,]   25  225  625 1225 2025 3025 4225 5625 7225  9025
 [6,]   36  256  676 1296 2116 3136 4356 5776 7396  9216
 [7,]   49  289  729 1369 2209 3249 4489 5929 7569  9409
 [8,]   64  324  784 1444 2304 3364 4624 6084 7744  9604
 [9,]   81  361  841 1521 2401 3481 4761 6241 7921  9801
[10,]  100  400  900 1600 2500 3600 4900 6400 8100 10000
```

The reason I mention this is that there are likely substantial speed gains to doing it this way vs. `apply`.

Comment: Good one. Matrix algebra is bound to be faster than pretty much anything else.

Comment: +1 -- let's also mention `col(ndat)` and `row(ndat)` as potential inputs to that vectorized function, in case it must use what the OP referred as `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 4):

From `?apply`:

> MARGIN: a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be
>             applied over.  E.g., for a matrix ‘1’ indicates rows, ‘2’
>             indicates columns, ‘c(1, 2)’ indicates rows and columns.
>             Where ‘X’ has named dimnames, it can be a character vector
>             selecting dimension names.

So you want:

```
ndat<-matrix(c(1:100), ncol=10)
apply(ndat, 1:2, cat)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua. As I have explained above with more realistic code I do need to access the indices of the matrix. The original example to cat the matrix was the simplest one I could think of to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Then just use a for loop. `sapply` and `outer` are designed to _return_ something for each iteration, but you're just using them for their side-effects, which is exactly what a for loop is for.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing can be simulated as this:

```
apply(ndat, 1, function (k) cat(k, "\n"))
```